# MYSQL datetime rows from 7 days ago?

Tags: mysql

Trying all sorts of things but coming up empty handed at the moment. I have it running hardcoded like this:

```
WHERE (activities.created_at BETWEEN '2015-08-07 00:00:00'
                              AND '2015-08-07 23:59:59.999')
```

I'm just trying to automate it a bit so I don't have to go in there every day and change the date to whatever it was 7 days ago.

My most recent test is:

```
WHERE (`activities`.`created_at` = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

It isn't throwing an error, but rather showing an empty set when there should be 338 rows to show.

Comment: And the error is...? ...and my blind guess is use `now()` instead of `curdate()`... (edit: except `=` and `BETWEEN` are not really equivalent anyway)

Comment: This should be valid syntax in MySQL, even with `CURDATE()`.  Please post the error.

Comment: What is the error?  We can't really help unless we know what's going on.

Comment: Your question is not clear... please tell us *what is the problem*. If you're facing problems with dates and `between`, I recommend you read [this article by Aaron Bertrand: *"What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common? "*](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: I updated my post to note that it's showing an empty data set upon query execution. There should be over 300 rows to show.

Comment: Ah, an empty set is not an error.  if `created_at` is `DATETIME` type rather than a `DATE` type, as your BETWEEN implies, then `CURDATE()` isn't the right function unless you use `DATE(activites.created_at) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`.

Comment: That would be because your revamp is looking for records created at midnight seven days ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
where date(created_at) = CURDATE() - interval 7 day
```

Your problem is that the datatype on either side of the equal sign weren't the same. `created_at` is a datetime column, while `curdate()` returns a date. The above statement converts `created_at` to a date before comparing.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much. It looks like the extra code from Toad for MySQL was throwing things off a bit.

Comment: Note that wrapping a column in a function prevents MySQL from using an index range scan operation. This query pattern forces MySQL to evaluate the expression `date(created_at)` for *every* row in the table (or, every row that isn't excluded by some other predicate), and compare that to the literal. On large tables, this results in a noticeable impact to performance, vs a query plan with predicate on a "bare" column that can make effective use of an index.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks for the info, I did not know that.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it like this:

```
 WHERE `activities`.`created_at` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   AND `activities`.`created_at` <  DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

Use `CURDATE()` if you prefer, in place of `DATE(NOW())`.

My preference is to do a "less than" midnight of the following day.

Doing less than or equal to a value with time component of "23:59:59" will work fine, as long as resolution is down to second, which is what the MySQL DATETIME or TIMESTAMP is. Some databases support date time values with even more precision, down to 3ms in SQL Server, e.g. "23:59:59.982".

The "less than midnight of the following day" pattern works for date time values that are more precise than 1 sec.

Comment: Here's a blog post from Aaron Bertrand which advocates against using `BETWEEN` with datetime comparisons: [https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) , which goes into some detailed examples of how using BETWEEN can lead to unexpected (and undetected) problems.  Doing a `>=` and a `<` comparison avoids a lot of those problems, and makes the author's intent very clear.